# Different between assign value / operating add, times, minus to an object in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying out private(set) in playground.

Say, a person named Slippin Jimmy, his age property shouldn't able to operate outside person class since age variable have a private(set) prefix.

I can't direct assign a value to age property, But I can still operate age like plus 1, minus1, times it, I think this is because there's no new variable to store data,  no-matter how I operate age variable, it still hold same value from person class, right?

So what's different between + 1, - 1, * 1 and = 1 in this scenario?

```
class person {
   var name = "Slippin Jimmy"
   private(set) var age = 18
   func getOlder() {
      age = age + 1
       print(age)
   }
}
var saul = person()
print("saul's age is \(saul.age)")//saul's age is 18

saul.getOlder()//19

saul.age + 1 //20
saul.age - 1 //18
saul.age * 3 //57

//saul.age = 22//cannot assign to property: 'age' setter is inaccessible

print("saul's age is \(saul.age)")//saul's age is 19
```

Comment: What you need is learn more about the swift language specificly `class` because  `+ - *` is just math operation, while `=` is assigning value to a variable. `//saul.age = 22//cannot assign to property: 'age' setter is inaccessible` and this error you will understand when you understanding about the class in swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Person.age` has a private setter. That means you cannot *set* the value of `age` from outside of the class. You can still *talk about it* (access its value) though, because its getter is not private, and that is exactly what the code in question is doing - mention its value when describing some other number. All of these are *expressions* that do not set the value of `age`:

```
saul.age + 1
saul.age - 1
saul.age * 3
```

From top to bottom, they mean:

- the value that is one more than `saul.age`
- the value that is one less than `saul.age`
- the value that is three times more than `saul.age`

You're just talking about some numbers! :) On the other hand, if you have said:

```
saul.age = 20
```

Then it means "change `saul.age` to 20", and that is not allowed because `age` has a private setter.

Side note: in normal Swift files, expressions like `saul.age + 1` are not allowed at the top level. The fact that this compiles for you suggests that you are probably in a Swift Playground.

Comment: In ***"normal"*** Swift file, expression like `saul.age + 1` is definitely allowed at top level. You might get a warning about result being unused. You are thinking about projects that uses `@main` or `UIApplicationMain` that alters the entry point.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Are you sure? Even in projects that doesn't use `@main` or `@UIApplicationMain`, top level expressions aren't allowed anywhere except in the special entry point file, right? Just so that we are on the same page: do `swift package init --type executable`, and create a `Foo.swift`. Writing top level expressions in there will give you a compiler error.